# JQuery não está funcionando

Tags: jquery

Estou tendo problemas em fazer o jquery funcionar. Aqui está o `head` do meu HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="script" type="text/javascript" href="script.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

E aqui está o meu javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 580;
    var slides = $(".movie");
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    var slideShowInterval;
    var slideshowSpeed = 3000;

    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, slideshowSpeed);
    slides.wrapAll("<div id="slidesHolder"></div>");
    slides.css({"float": "left"});
    $("#slidesHolder").css("width", slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


    function changePosition() {
            if (currentPosition == numberOfSlides) {
                currentPosition = 1;
            }
            else {
                currentPosition += 1;
            }
            moveSlide();
    }

    function moveSlide() {
        $("#slideHolder").animate({"marginLeft": slideWidth * (-currentPosition)});
    }

});
```

O estranho é que já utilizei JQuery exatamente da mesma forma em outros sites antes, e ele funcionou perfeitamente. Já fiz o teste do `alert`, já tentei utilizar a biblioteca baixada em vez do CDN do Google, já tentei trocar a ordem dos `<script>` na `head` do HTML, e já procurei o mesmo problema em outros fóruns, mas sem sucesso de conseguir ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

O teu erro não é a carregar o JQuery, mas sim erro de sintaxe:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

No `slides.wrapAll` que estás a utilizar, falta retirar o valor das aspas `""` ao colocar o `id` da `div`.

Basta usares o `\` para tirar o valor das aspas, ou então podes usar plicas `'`:

```
slides.wrapAll("<div id=\"slidesHolder\"></div>");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdgnnhz1/) funcional.

Comment: Obrigada pelo aviso, porém mesmo assim o jquery não está funcionando. Fiz o teste do alert(); e nada acontece.

Comment: Faz F12 e vê o erro que está a dar na consola

Comment: Tá aqui sua resposta: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/fdgnnhz1/1/